# Install GCC on OpenSUSE 11.4

Tags: linux, opensuse, software-installation, gcc

I installed OpenSUSE 11.4 but I noticed that it don't have `gcc`…
How I can install it?

Answer (score 9):

```
sudo zypper install gcc
```

After that you're going to want to read some OpenSUSE documentation before you ask any more questions.